# write Golang unit test for function that expects a key pressed to continue

Tags: unit-testing, go

I have a function in Golang something like this:

```
func Exit(code int) {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    keyboard.Open()
    defer keyboard.Close()
    keyboard.GetKey()
    PrintAndLogInfo("\nBye.")
    os.Exit(code)
}
```

I am using the following library to use this keyboard feature

```
github.com/eiannone/keyboard
```

I would like to write unit tests for this function. However, the keyboard.GetKey() expects a key pressed. And maybe because of that when I run my test that calls the function `Exit`, it fails with the error:

panic: function GetKey() should be called after Open() [recovered]
panic: function GetKey() should be called after Open()

Do I need to mock something here in order to fix this error? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the error `function GetKey() should be called after Open()` is triggered by `keyboard.GetKey()`. It seems `GetKey()` thinks `Open()` was never called.
Now, in your example, we do see `keyboard.Open()` - but `Open()` can actually return an `error`, which you seem to ignore.
So you should check what the error is and deal with that in your code.

However, that doesn't actually solve your problem - because you probably do not want to press a key every time your unit tests are ran (especially not on your CI environment).

Like you say, I would mock the keyboard library. That is: write an interface that does the things you need, write an implementation of that interface that simple calls the `keyboard` library and write a mock implementation to help testing. That mock can then directly return from `GetKey()` (or whatever you call it in *your* interface). A more advances mock could have some configuration to return directly, sleep a bit or never return.

I've created a quick example of how that would work, see https://gist.github.com/jorygeerts/e887856cc15b64cb9681639cd83c4a37. Note that for your tests, you probably also want to inject something to mock `os.Exit()` and perhaps also your `PrintAndLogInfo`.

Comment: Could you explain with some code? I am  new to Go and just starting to write unit tests for a small app I am writing. As a beginner, at this time I am not even clear on the best/right way to mock things in Go

Comment: @user1892775 Do you mean an example of the interface, its implementation and the mock?

Comment: Yes, basically anything that is easy enough to provide that would help me understand better. Again only if its easy enough to provide. If its lot of work, then its a different story, I would try to figure out myself in that case.

Comment: @user1892775 I've created a (admittedly rather rough) small example that I hope will show you what I mean.